# How to connect list item to div element javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a vertical tabs, but the list items should be connected to the divs seperately. All the divs are hidden with display: none; and when someone clicks on for example tab2, the second div should be turned into display: block. In other words, the className "selected" will be added to that specific div. Got the following error in console.log (Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLUListElement.). Anyone here who knows how to write the JavaScript so the list items are connected to the divs.

Only in plain JavaScript please.

```js
document.getElementById("verticalUl").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event,
  elements = document.getElementById("verticalUl").children, 
  content = document.querySelectorAll(".support-box");

    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") { 
     var attribute = e.target.getAttribute("id");
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("active-support");
            
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
             content[i].classList.remove("selected");
            };
        document.querySelector("." + attribute + "-box").classList.add("selected");
        e.target.classList.add("active-support");
    }
});
```

```css
.group {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  display: block;
}
.vertical-navbar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.vertical-navbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.support-box {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="vertical-navbar" id="verticalUl">
    <li id="tab1" class="support-tabs-label active-support">Hot Topics</li>

    <li id="tab2" class="support-tabs-label">Account</li>

    <li id="tab3" class="support-tabs-label">Product</li>

    <li id="tab4" class="support-tabs-label">Order and Shipping</li>
</ul>
            
<div class="content-support1  support-box tab1-box group selected">
Hot Topics
</div>

<div class="content-support2 support-box tab2-box group">
Account
</div>

<div class="content-support3 support-box tab3-box group">
Product
</div>

<div class="content-support4 support-box tab4-box group">
Order and Shipping
</div>
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: decorate the `li` with data attribute like `data-divName='support1'`, give your div this `id=support1` and then when the user clicks on the `li` element read the data attribute which will be the id of the div and then add ur class to it. [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that all of the `support-box` elements have `tabx-box`, where `tabx` matches the clicked `li` element, you can simply use:

```
document.querySelector("." + attribute + "-box").classList.add("selected");
```

**The Solution**

```
document.getElementById("verticalUl").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event,
        elements = document.getElementById("verticalUl").children, 
        content = document.querySelectorAll(".support-box");

    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        content[i].classList.remove("selected");
    }

    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") { 
        var attribute = e.target.getAttribute("id");

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("active-support");
        }

        e.target.classList.add("active-support");
        document.querySelector("." + attribute + "-box").classList.add("selected");
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j8k09r9s/1/